# Помогите подключить кодировку в файле подключения к бд

Tags: php, mysql

Вот сам файл

```
<?php
class DBController {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "7";
    private $password = "040366";
    private $database = "7";

    function __construct() {
        $conn = $this->connectDB();
        if(!empty($conn)) {
            $this->selectDB($conn);
        }


    }

    function connectDB() {
        $conn = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
        return $conn;

    }

    function selectDB($conn) {
        mysql_select_db($this->database,$conn);
    }

    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }

    function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysql_query($query);
        $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;   
    }
}
?>
```

Каким образом можно подключить кодировку `SET NAMES utf8` , не выводится на русском из базы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
mysql_query ("set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Comment: Спасибо , куда правильно вписывать это , ругается когда добавляю

Comment: [Здесь почитайте](http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-database/thread198468.html)

Comment: Спасибо почитал , вопрос не решился, у меня в другом файле подключается вот таким образом, `private function __construct() {
            $this->_handle = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASSWORD, DB_BASE);
            if ($this->_handle->connect_error) {
                die('Connect Error (' . $this->_handle->connect_errno . ') ' . $this->_handle->connect_error);
            }
            $this->_handle->query("SET NAMES utf8");
        }` ну а здесь как только не тыкаю , то ошибка , то не меняется кодировка

Comment: А почему не подключить просто файл с классом DBController и вызвать функцию __construct()?

Comment: это с другого файла base.php  к данному скрипту никакого отношения не имеет, я не понимаю куда и как втыкнуть правильно `"SET NAMES utf8"` для того что б выводилась русская кодировка , в файле который указан в вопросе

Comment: Необходимо явно сообщать MySQL в какой кодировке вы собираетесь работать с базой данных. Запрос может выглядеть следующим образом

http://www.codesend.com/view/9129954a5d22b01c80d084efa2257efd/

Comment: Надо хоть иногда заглядывать в руководство даже по ПХП. "Замечание:
Это наиболее предпочитаемый способ для смены кодировки. Использование mysql_query() в этих целях (например SET NAMES utf8) не рекомендуется." Это замечание к функции mysql_set_charset(). http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Comment: Я понимаю , спасибо, на обычных пхп без конструкторов этих я ставил кодировку, все дела ... но именно загвоздка из за этого , подключение то к базе идет   `$conn = $this->connectDB();` , и я сижу голову ломаю куда и каким образом всё это сделать

Comment: Извините))) спасибо вам))